# How to create connection object for PreparedStatement in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot

```
            try (Connection connection = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql_database?useSSL=false", "root", "root");

            // Step 2:Create a statement using connection object
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(UPDATE_USERS_SQL)) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "Ram");
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, 1);

            // Step 3: Execute the query or update query
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Creating connection object for each query and closing it is expensive, is there any other way to use prepared statement with spring boot and secondly How do I create connection object, I have database information in application.yml file

Comment: You can use spring JDBC API for this.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Creating connection object for each query and closing it is expensive

That's exactly the reason to use connection pools, like c3p0, dbcp, or more modern Hikari connection pool with which spring boot 2 ecosystem integrates perfectly. To access the data you probably may want to use a thin wrapper over raw JDBC API which is fairly cumbersome. Spring provides a wrapper like this, its called `JdbcTemplate` (It much less "advanced" than hibernate, it doesn't do any automatical mapping, doesn't generate crazy and not-so-crazy queries), it acts pretty much like jdbc but saves you from creating Prepared Statements, iterating over result sets, etc.

I won't really explain here how to use JdbcTemplate, I'll just state that you may get a connection from it but I don't think you'll ever need it.
Of course under the hood it will be integrated with Hikari connection pool, so that the actual connection will be taken from the pool.

[Here](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jdbc-examples/) you can find an example of such a facility with full DAO implementation (its called repository) and JdbcTemplate object configuration